# Twilio SMS messages not going through

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, twilio

I have added Twilio SMS access key to my app and I'm able to hardcode my AT&T cell phone number into the to field and I can receive the text successfully, but for some reason when I try and test it by sending a message to 2 different people. One with verizon and the other with TMobile, they never receive the message? Why is that?
I appreciate any help!

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const twilioClient = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);



module.exports = function (context, req) {
  console.log(req.body.phoneNumber)

  let phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber.replace(/\D+/g, "");
  console.log(phoneNumber);
  try {
    twilioClient.messages
      .create({
        body: `Site Verification Code: ${req.body.code}`,
        from: '13134257967',
        to: '<my number>'
      })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
    console.log("sent");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "SMS Validation ERROR",
      error: err
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Is this a trial account? If so, the destination numbers need to be verified, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio. Also, check the Debugger for errors - https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/debugging-tools

Comment: I didn't realize I had to verify numbers for trial account. I created the account months ago. I guess I forgot that I added my own number. Thanks!